# Disable and enable two buttons for same condition(while typing in forms) angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular5

I have a formfield named **value**. I have a **add** button. When I click the **add**  button it duplicates the form field. I have written code in such a way that when I enter a value(say 40) in formfield and then click **add** button and enter another value say (50),I have a function which adds the sum of these values and compare it with the **Totalvalue** above.If its greater than the **totalvalue** the a error message pops up.

Now what I need is that when my sum of the form values is equal to the **totalvalue** above I need to disable the **add** button and enable my **submit** button.I tried it a certain way by using `[disabled]="isin"`  and assigned boolean to disable and enable. But thsi didnt work as I expected.(Because if I enter a value greater than **totalvalue** the **add** button gets disabled and when I hit backspace its still disabled)

Note:Please comment below If my question was unclear

My stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fc8tcl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SB example, the logic around switching the value of `this.isin` doesn't get re-triggered after it's been set to `true`.

A more straightforward solution would be to replace

```js
if (this.total <= sum) {
  this.isin = !this.isin;
}
```

with

```js
this.isin = this.total === sum;
```

Also, change the `[disabled]` binding on the Add button to use the returned value from the `checkTotal` call, and use `isin` to bind to the Submit button, like this

```html
<button ... [disabled]="!checkTotal()" ><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Add</button>
...
<button type="submit" ... [disabled]="!isin">Submit</button>
```

Working SB link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mwywpt?file=src/app/app.component.ts

One more thing to note: `checkTotal()` doesn't get called when a value is deleted, so you have to change one of the input values to get the value of `isin` to re-calculate

Comment: But I needed to use<= to meet the condition. So I have changed that. The add enable disable is fine,But in this stackblitz you haven't enabled and disabled for submit. I tried the same method you used for add button but its not working @Cineris

Comment: @Leno Sorry, I misread it at first. I've updated the answer and the SB link. The Submit button needs be driven from `isin` and the Add button needs to use the value returned from `checkTotal()`

Comment: Thanks but the add button is not disabling when the sum of form values is equal to the total value  @Cineris

Comment: @Leno to fix that, you just have to change `if (sum > this.total) ` to `if (sum >= this.total) ` in `checkTotal` on line 66. Stackblitz has been updated

Comment: I also updated the logic around the `showError` call to use both the `checkValue()` return value and `this.isin`

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track, but if you want to have that behavior you need to subscribe on the formControl's `valueChanges` event, there you check if the sum is equal, greater or lesser than your expected value, and enable/disable the boolean for the buttons.

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges